# Metro UI - multiple snapped view on one monitor, desktop on the other one

Tags: windows-8, desktop, modern-ui

I tried Googling that but I didn't get anything so now I post it here.

How I can get multiple snapped view (multi-app) on my second monitor while running my Desktop app on the primary one?

It would be useful to have multiple snapped like this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

1. Drag an app to the second screen.
2. Using the second screen's app list (top left hot corner **on the second screen**) drag another app into the second screen.

Things get rather finicky working like this though. If you go to the Start screen this all resets.

Snapping with multiple monitors was not well thought out for the initial release of Windows 8.